# Question relating to the probability and binomial distribution

Tags: probability

A sampling plan works as follows: a sample of 20 is selected from a large group of similar items.  The whole group is approved for shipment if 2 or fewer of the samples are defective.  If one percent of the larger group is defective, find the probability that it will be approved for shipment.

Comment: Hint: Check out the hypergeometric distribution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^2 {20 \choose n} .01^n (1 - .01)^{20-n} = 0.998996$$

Answer (score 1):

As Ramiro suggested, this is hypergeometric distribution, so if we have $a$ defective products and $b=99a$ OK products. So the probability is $$P= {{a\choose 0}{b\choose 20} +{a\choose 1}{b\choose 19}+ {a\choose 2}{b\choose 18} \over {100a\choose 20}}$$

But this is rather robust to calculate so it is better to use binomial approximation (this we can since group is large). So the probability that single product is bad is $p=0.01$ and that is good is $q=1-p = 0.99$. We choose 20 products so $$P= {20\choose 0}p^0q^{20}+{20\choose 1}p^1q^{19}+{20\choose 2}p^2q^{18}$$